# Geocode points with append data ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, geocoding, append

I am trying to add points with address data in a .csv file to a hosted layer in ArcGIS Online with the hops of ArcGIS geocoding the points for me. When I try to append the data, I am prompted to provide location information (longitude and latitude) I read this post on the ArcGIS site and it suggests it's possible. https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/append-feature-service-layer-.htm

I am able to have points geocoded when I add a new layer, but I would prefer not to have to add a new layer each time I have new data.

Comment: What is your level license of ArcGIS Server and what app are you using in the field?

Comment: The layer is hosted on ArcGIS Online, not server, and the app being used is Collector.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.